# Quantum measurements

Tags: measurements, quantum-computer

I am reading the paper "[Unconditionaly verifiable blind computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5217)". 
It says at p.9:

> a measurement in the $\lbrace \vert +_{\phi_i^{\prime}}\rangle, \vert -_{\phi_i^{\prime}} \rangle\rbrace $ basis on a state $\vert \psi\rangle$ is the same as a measurement in the $\lbrace \vert +_{\phi_i^{\prime}+\theta_i}\rangle$ basis on $Z(\theta_i) \vert \psi\rangle$.

I wrote it in this form:
$$\vert +_{\phi_i^{\prime}}\rangle\langle+_{\phi_i^{\prime}}\vert = \vert +_{\phi_i^{\prime}+\theta_i}\rangle\langle+_{\phi_i^{\prime}+\theta_i}\vert Z(\theta_i)$$
then, I multiplied their $2\times 2$ matrices but I don't get the same results.

Am I right?

**Measurement $M_i^\alpha $** is defined by orthogonal projections on
\begin{align}
\vert +_\alpha\rangle & := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\vert 0\rangle+e^{i\alpha} \vert 1\rangle\big), \\
\vert -_\alpha\rangle & := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\vert 0\rangle-e^{i\alpha} \vert 1\rangle\big)
\end{align}
followed by a trace out operator.

The parameter $\alpha \in [0, 2\pi]$ is called the angle of the measurement.

Comment: Hint: in $\vert +_{\phi_i^{\prime}}\rangle\langle+_{\phi_i^{\prime}}\vert = \vert +_{\phi_i^{\prime}+\theta_i}\rangle\langle+_{\phi_i^{\prime}+\theta_i}\vert Z(\theta_i)$, the left-hand side is hermitian and the right-hand side isn't, so it cannot be true as stated.

Comment: Do you know how I can correct my proof?

Comment: please help me!may be it has another method for prove.

Comment: My hint for your other question was to use matrix multiplication on equations (2) and (3). Does what you did look like either equation (2) or (3)? Didn't these equations involve multiplication of ***three*** terms?

Comment: your hint was useful. Yes, I guess it should be another term here that disregarded for simplification. because in the measurement calculus paper  for obtain the eq. 4 and eq. 5 from eq. 2 and eq. 3 the author says "since the measurements considered here are destructive, the above equations simplify to eq. 4 and eq. 5. however I can't understand or convince by  this reason well!

Comment: and if there was another term in the present question which disregarded, what term it can be! and why it can be disregarded?thanks for your attention.

Comment: Your other question had $Z_iM^α_iZ_i$ in Eq. 3. What you've multiplied in this question is $M^α_iZ_i$.

Comment: In this equation, we have z-rotation instead of pauli Z. but what do you mean Mr. Shor?if you multiply a z-rotation in the Rhs of this equation after the measurement  implemented, you can't get the Lhs, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we write the measurement in the form $\langle +_{\phi_{i}}\mid$, so we can write measurements in this form and we get the same result:
$ \langle +_{\phi_{i}^{\prime}}\mid = \langle +_{\phi_{i}^{\prime}+\theta_{i}} \mid Z(\theta_{i})$.

Comment: The "measurement calculus" paper uses this term for measurement in the examples  and it works for these equations. (I didn't saw before) but,  why do we use   $< +_{\phi} |$ instead of $\mid +_{\phi}> < +_{\phi} | $ ? do you know?

Comment: Do anyone knows my answer?